# "Es kostet 500 Euro" or "Er kostet 500 Euro"?

Tags: word-usage, personal-pronoun

Which is correct?

- *Es* kostet 500 Euro.
- *Er* kostet 500 Euro.

I understand if *der* is used like *der Laptop*, we use *er kostet* and if *das* is used like in *das Buch*, we will use *es kostet* for its cost.

Please, help correct my understanding.

Comment: Both may be correct depending on the context, which was not provided. (Just to mention, that a laptop is concerned, does not help to answer that.)

Comment: You ask which version is correct and then answer it yourself by giving correct examples for both versions. So I am not sure, what exactly your question is. Or did you just need a confirmation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right: grammatically speaking, the pronoun should be picked according to the noun it replaces.

> Wieviel kostet das Buch?
>   Es kostet 500 Euro.

and

> Wieviel kostet der Topf?
>   Er kostet 500 Euro.

As others mention, though, depending on the context and particularly when it comes to spoken language, other - sometimes grammatically incorrect - versions tend to be used:

> Wieviel kostet der Topf?
>   Der kostet 500 Euro.
>   Dieser kostet 500 Euro.

or even sometimes:

> Es kostet 500 Euro.

because one uses the neutral form to speak about an unnamed object, regardless of its gender. E.g. pointing at the Topf:

> Das mag ich.

Comment: Please note that you can say both, "der Laptop" and "das Laptop", this should be remarked in this answer!

Comment: Good catch! My bad. I'll use a Topf instead of a Laptop.

Comment: _Er_ is more common for (male) persons, especially when _er_  is at position 3: _Wir hatten einen guten DJ kommen lassen, **der**_ (non spoken: er) _nahm 40 Euro pro Stunde. Ab Mitternacht wollte **er** 60 Euro, aber wir konnten **ihn** auf 50 Euro herunterhandeln._

Comment: Wenn Du auf einen Topf deutest und sagst "Das mag ich", dann vielleicht, weil Du das auf den Topf deuten magst; der Topf dagegen erfordert "Den mag ich.". Wenn Du auf die Stielkasserolle deutest, dann darfst Du "die" sagen, bei einem Küchenaccessoir auch "das", nur ist es dann eben nicht der Topf, sondern das Küchenaccessoir. Statt "das Objekt" kommt auch meist "der Gegenstand" oder "die Entität" in Betracht.

Answer (score 2):

Even though both are grammatically correct (`Es kostet` and `Das kostet` or `Er kostet` and `Der kostet`), I would personally prefer saying `das` or `der` over `es` or `er`. I can't really explain it logically but it seems more common to me as a native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

The word for 'it' can be er(der),sie(die) and es(das) depending on the definite article of the object you are referring to.

For Laptop(der) - Er kostet 500 Euro.

For Buch(das) - Es kostet 500 Euro.

For Tasche(die) - Sie kostet 500 Euro.

Comment: I will never say *he* / *er* in such cases, but always *der*.

Comment: Laptop can also be neutral i.e. "Das Laptop kostet"

Answer (score -2):

I recommend to avoid the personal pronoun.

*kostet* is lexicalized as an active verb, *Ich koste*,  but it is frequently understood as kind of compromise between active and passive, *das kostet dich*, avoiding an explicit subject. Because who sets the price? The item on sale itself does not set its own price.

Historically the term might have described labor wage, so *Er kostet* may be fully active, i.e. in the sense *He demands, receives, eats X rations per day*; cp *Diätenerhöhung*, *Kost und Logie*; but that's not and probably never was the primary meaning of *kosten* "to taste"; cp Latin ...

Anyhow, it is completely legal to say *Es/das* in line with *Es regnet*, *es versteht sich von selbst*, *es gefällt ihm dort*, etc etc, without aducing a concrete, gendered subject. Since *der, die, das* can be understood as short for *der Laptop*, etc. using a personal pronoun instead would sound--to me at least--almost like *it Laptop costs*; funny enough, I could get used to that: "Es kostet der Laptop ..." is nevertheless unusual.

Further, I'd frequently admit an ambiguous contraction, "Der  andere Markt hat'n für 250 im Angebot". If we were talking about a person, it would use self-reflexivity instead "Er hat sich für 250/h im Angebot", if not active "Er bietet sich für ...", so that no confusion over *ihn/den* can arrise; I would be inclined to prefer *ihn* in the prior Markt example, but am ultimately undecided, because I am not aware of a legal argument against either way. I guess, *diesen* doesn't help either. But *den gleichen* or any construction that quallifies the determiner with an attribute would be preferable over a misunderstood pronoun.

Comment: Ich halt es für eine sinnvollere Idee, wenn du solche Ausflüge auf einem Blog sammelst, statt hier bestenfalls peripher die Frage zu streifen

Comment: @infinitezero Auf derartige Vorwürfe muss ich verhalten reagieren. Vielleicht würde es helfen, wenn du deine Idee für dich hältst, statt dich zurückhaltend auszudrücken. Du leidest wohl an Leseschwäche, oder bist einfach nur zu faul mitzudenken oder wat?